# Subdomain Stopped Linking to Folders (CSS & JS)

Tags: php, html, css

A site I'm working on has a subdomain, canada.archwaysandceilings.com. It used to work fine, but all of a sudden the site isn't accessing the CSS or JS folders...I've checked the links to those files, and they are correct.

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The "css" folder is within the same directory as index.php, and I've already verified the file IS there (although the site says it's not). If you go to canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/, you'll see the file there, but if you go to canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css, it says the file can't be found.

The same thing is happening with other folders; yet the folders containing actual PHP pages work fine (such as canada.archwaysandceilings.com/archways/).

I've checked the server permissions for the folder, and they seem fine as well; everyone can read them.

I did download the file directly from the server, to see if perhaps something happened to the contents, but it appears fine and intact.

Here are the contents of the .htaccess file for the Canada subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName archkit.com
AuthUserFile /home/archw11/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/archw11/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

Comment: Are you running apache? Looks like some sort of mod_rewrite issue? Does your CSS get served through PHP at all?

Comment: Some web hosts use a 'referrer' check to constrain which web pages can include assets.  You might check with your admins to see if that was a "feature" that was recently configured on.

Comment: Do you have your subdomain website files in sub folder ?

Comment: Yes, this is on Apache. How do I find out if my CSS gets served through PHP?

@PaulProgrammer: by "admins" do you mean web host?

I temporarily fixed it simply by adding the differences to the CSS file for the main domain; i.e. I linked it to "archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css", just so it would work. But I would REALLY like to know the reason that I can't link to folders within the Canada subdirectory. :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Specify full link to the css and js

```
 <link href="http://www.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And same thing applies for javascript.

Comment: That would link to an entirely different css file; I did try to link to "canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css", but it didn't work. for some reason, the browser (or the server) is saying the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Check your .htacess file if you have one and show us what is there

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question to include the .htaccess file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your website calls for `http://canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css`, but your resource is located at `http://archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css`.  Just change the link to use the latter.

was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rollovers.js"></script>
```

works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://archwaysandceilings.com/js/rollovers.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's because there IS one at canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css. I just don't understand why it won't read from the files in the "canada" subdirectory. They ARE there, I double checked.

Comment: You might want to check that assumption from the outside world.  When I point my web browser at `http://canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css` I get a 404 error.

Answer (score -3):

You can try to spell the full path

```
<link href="http://canada.archwaysandceilings.com/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```